# Reorder column values so that the same values are always in the same column for a group

Tags: r

Is there a way to reorder data in columns based on group. Notice the data order switched columns [CD1 and CD2], [PR1 and PR2], [TR1 and TR2] for record 2 compared to record 1. The order could be switched for any record so that the same values for same label are always in the same column (perhaps we can order it by numerical value). Basically the idea is to put same values in same order for easy comparisons.

```
    mydata<-
structure(list(record_id = c(1L, 2L, 2L), label = c("ABC", "ABC", 
"ABC"), inst = c(1L, 1L, 2L), Loc = c("CAB", "CAB", "JAB"), CD1 = c("a123B", 
"tmz123b", "tmz12"), PR1 = c("b123c", "tm123n", "tm13n"), TR1 = c("ab123", 
"tm245", "tm245"), CD2 = c("tmz123b", "a123B", "a13B"), PR2 = c("tm123n", 
"b123c", "b13c"), TR2 = c("tm245", "ab123", "ab12")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

desired output:
record_id   label   inst    Loc CD1 PR1 TR1 CD2 PR2 TR2
1   ABC 1   CAB a123B   b123c   ab123   tmz123b tm123n  tm245
2   ABC 1   CAB a123B   b123c   ab123   tmz123b tm123n  tm245
2   ABC 2   JAB tmz12   tm13n   tm245   a13B    b13c    ab12

library(data.table)
cols <- c("CD1", "CD2")
setDT(mydata)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, sort), by = .(record_id, Loc), .SDcols = cols][]

# If we can sort CD1 and CD2 regardless of any grouping that should work as well.
```

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` or `mydata` assignment in code?  It's a little hard to see which column names and columns go together with the post's formatting.

Comment: @andrew_reece added dput of mydata

Comment: It's not really clear what the desired transformation is.  You switch column values with a "1" and "2" suffix in row 2, but how does that satisfy "so that the same values for the same label are always in the same column"?  And why do you group by record_id and Loc in the data.table code?  You only mention record and label in your post.  If you can explain the rules you want to implement more clearly - and maybe add a few rows to `mydata` to make it clearer how the rules work (what happens when one ID has 3 rows for example?) - that will make it easier to get useful help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried to be clearer in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77114738/arrange-dataframe-such-that-same-values-end-up-in-the-same-column-for-all-record

Answer (score -1):

The basic form of what you want is to `apply` `sort()` to every row.
Like:

```
desired <- cbind(
    mydata[, 1:4],
    t(apply(mydata[, 5:ncol(mydata)], 1, sort))
)
```

It would be a bit complicated if `group_by` is needed.
Also, you only want to sort across [CD1 and CD2], [PR1 and PR2], [TR1 and TR2].
You can do it within different subsets and binds them back.