# Arrange dataframe such that same values end up in the same column for all records

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe consisting of thousands of rows and 5 columns. I want to order Columns AT1 and AT2 for each row such that same values always end up in the same column for each row. Notice row 10 and 11. The values are switched between AT1 and AT2. Is there a way to always have same values in the same column for all records?

```
mydata<-structure(list(record_id = 1:19, Loc = c("ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", 
"ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", 
"ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT", "ROTT"
), repeat. = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AT1 = c("m.657+5G>A_NA", "m.657+5G>A_NA", 
"m.657+5G>A_NA", "m.1501C>T_NA", "m.1501C>T_NA", "m.1501C>T_NA", 
"m.687C>G_NA", "m.687C>G_NA", "m.687C>G_NA", "m.2512G>A_NA", 
"m.1538G>A_NA", "m.2840-2A>G_NA", "m.2840-2A>G_NA", "m.2840-2A>G_NA", 
"m.2111T>C_NA", "m.2111T>C_NA", "m.1549-2A>G_NA", "m.1549-2A>G_NA", 
"m.1549-2A>G_NA"), AT2 = c("<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "m.1538G>A_NA", "m.2512G>A_NA", 
"<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>", "<NA>"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

This is what I tried which doesn't do the job

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("AT1", "AT2")
setDT(mydata)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, sort), by = .(record_id, Loc), .SDcols = cols][]
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the question. If the values for row 10 and 11 are "switched" check the code that created these values. It looks like the output you stored in column AT2 was ordered the "other way". Ditto, if you build your `mydata` in a row-by-row manner. Make sure that ordering is how you expect it. Hope that helps. I would not recommend to swap results in the columns AT1 and AT2 "cross-wise". While it might be straight forward for the example you posted here ( e.g. swap column A row x with column B row x+1, etc and vice-versa), thousands of rows and 5 columns sound like a challenge.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35891340/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pmin/pmax:

```
mydata[, .(AT1 = pmax(AT1, AT2), AT2 = pmin(AT1, AT2)) ]

#               AT1          AT2
# 1:  m.657+5G>A_NA         <NA>
# 2:  m.657+5G>A_NA         <NA>
# 3:  m.657+5G>A_NA         <NA>
# 4:   m.1501C>T_NA         <NA>
# 5:   m.1501C>T_NA         <NA>
# 6:   m.1501C>T_NA         <NA>
# 7:    m.687C>G_NA         <NA>
# 8:    m.687C>G_NA         <NA>
# 9:    m.687C>G_NA         <NA>
#10:   m.2512G>A_NA m.1538G>A_NA
#11:   m.2512G>A_NA m.1538G>A_NA
#12: m.2840-2A>G_NA         <NA>
#13: m.2840-2A>G_NA         <NA>
#14: m.2840-2A>G_NA         <NA>
#15:   m.2111T>C_NA         <NA>
#16:   m.2111T>C_NA         <NA>
#17: m.1549-2A>G_NA         <NA>
#18: m.1549-2A>G_NA         <NA>
#19: m.1549-2A>G_NA         <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to order Columns AT1 and AT2 for each row such that same values
> always end up in the same column for each row.

I'll interpret this to mean that when a value, e.g., `"m.1538G>A_NA"` appears, it should always be in the same column. This will only be possible if the graph formed from undirected edges connecting `AT1` to `AT2` is [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). We can check this condition using `igraph::bipartite.mapping`, which will also provide which disjoint set the vertex belongs to. We can use this information to order the columns.

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)

cols <- c("AT1", "AT2")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(unique(mydata[,cols]), FALSE)
bm <- bipartite.mapping(g)

# the graph is bipartite if `bm$res` is `TRUE`
if (bm$res) setDT(mydata)[!bm$type[match(AT1, names(V(g)))], (cols) := .(AT2, AT1)]
mydata
#>     record_id  Loc repeat.          AT1            AT2
#>  1:         1 ROTT       1         <NA>  m.657+5G>A_NA
#>  2:         2 ROTT       2         <NA>  m.657+5G>A_NA
#>  3:         3 ROTT       3         <NA>  m.657+5G>A_NA
#>  4:         4 ROTT       1         <NA>   m.1501C>T_NA
#>  5:         5 ROTT       1         <NA>   m.1501C>T_NA
#>  6:         6 ROTT       1         <NA>   m.1501C>T_NA
#>  7:         7 ROTT       1         <NA>    m.687C>G_NA
#>  8:         8 ROTT       1         <NA>    m.687C>G_NA
#>  9:         9 ROTT       1         <NA>    m.687C>G_NA
#> 10:        10 ROTT       1 m.1538G>A_NA   m.2512G>A_NA
#> 11:        11 ROTT       1 m.1538G>A_NA   m.2512G>A_NA
#> 12:        12 ROTT       1         <NA> m.2840-2A>G_NA
#> 13:        13 ROTT       1         <NA> m.2840-2A>G_NA
#> 14:        14 ROTT       1         <NA> m.2840-2A>G_NA
#> 15:        15 ROTT       1         <NA>   m.2111T>C_NA
#> 16:        16 ROTT       1         <NA>   m.2111T>C_NA
#> 17:        17 ROTT       1         <NA> m.1549-2A>G_NA
#> 18:        18 ROTT       1         <NA> m.1549-2A>G_NA
#> 19:        19 ROTT       1         <NA> m.1549-2A>G_NA
```

A simple example where the graph is not bipartite:

```
(mydata <- data.table(id = 1:3, AT1 = 1:3, AT2 = c(3L, 1L, 2L)))
#>    id AT1 AT2
#> 1:  1   1   3
#> 2:  2   2   1
#> 3:  3   3   2
g <- graph_from_data_frame(unique(mydata[,..cols]), FALSE)
bipartite.mapping(g)$res
#> [1] FALSE
```

There's no way to arrange `AT1` and `AT2` in each row so that each value appears in only one column.